# Show footer menu on scroll bottom page

Tags: scroll, hide, footer, show, slidetoggle

I have a script for showing the footer menu on scroll on the bottom of the page fixed and it works, but when opening the page or reload in the beginning the footer menu is visible. And after scrolling it reacts the way i want. It properly is quite simple but my head doesn't function at the moment.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
    $( 'footer').slideDown(300);
} else {
    console.log('there');
    $('footer').slideUp(300);
}});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/afgp3ctg/)

**Solved it my self i was thinking to difficult i forgot to set display: none; on the footer.**

Answer (score 1):

I changed one line in your css code below:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    bottom: 0;
    /* just make the footer display:none when page loading */
    display: none;
    z-index: 300;
}
```

And here is a link fork your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abruzzi/afgp3ctg/3/

Comment: Yess i find it out this morning and edit my post, totally forgot to set display to none. #-) thanks for helping anyway ;-)